# XML::Simple how to prevent <name> content substitution with the refference?

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I try to parse an xml document using XML::Simple perl parsing.
I noticed, if the document looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fields>
  <field>
    <f1>1234</f1>
    <name>MyName1</name>
  </field>
</fields>
```

the result of print(Dumper($ref)); looks as expected:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'field' => {
                     'f1' => '1234',
                     'name' => 'MyName1'
                   }
        };
```

while if I have more than one  list in the document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fields>
  <field>
    <f1>1234</f1>
    <name>MyName1</name>
  </field>
  <field>
    <f1>567</f1>
    <name>MyName2</name>
  </field>
</fields>
```

the results looks like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'field' => {
                     'MyName1' => {
                                  'f1' => '1234'
                                },
                     'MyName2' => {
                                  'f1' => '567'
                                }
                   }
        };
```

while expected results would be:

```
    $VAR1 = { [
              'field' => {
                         'f1' => '1234',
                         'name' => 'MyName1'
                       },
              'field' => {
                         'f1' => '567',
                         'name' => 'MyName2'
                       }
              ]
            };
```

what options of XML::Simple parser will prevent  tag content substitution with the tag reference and use an array of `<field>` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default. XML::Simple names hash keys by the values of tags `<name>`, `<key>` and `<id>`. You can customize this behavior via [KeyAttr setting](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSimple#KeyAttr-list-in-out---important).
Thus, the code which produces the structure closest to what you expect is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;

local $/ = undef;
say Dumper XMLin(<DATA>, KeyAttr => []);

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fields>
  <field>
    <f1>1234</f1>
    <name>MyName1</name>
  </field>
  <field>
    <f1>567</f1>
    <name>MyName2</name>
  </field>
</fields>
```

And here is the output:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'field' => [
                 {
                   'f1' => '1234',
                   'name' => 'MyName1'
                 },
                 {
                   'f1' => '567',
                   'name' => 'MyName2'
                 }
               ]
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `ForceArray => 'field'` option to `XMLin`.

In general you cannot mold the data structures that `XML::Simple` returns to whatever you want them to. `XML::Simple` is too simple for that. However, your use case is one that is described in the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSimple#ForceArray-names-in---important). I suggest you read the documentation to all items that are marked as `important` at least, because it really helps knowing what your options are in shaping structures returned by `XML::Simple`.

Comment: Also works, however, the `KeyAttr` setting addresses the issue in a more direct fashion :)

Comment: the issue with ForceArray is that it arraying everything, I mean each internal element goes into an array. And it requires substantial change in other code (to get the elements out of the arrays). I agree with creaktive, KeyAttr addresses the issue straightforwardly and gives the result I need. But thank you anyway for your input